# How to perform the following curl request in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, curl, request

I am exhausted after searching a lot, but still have no idea.

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "app_id: yyyyyyyy" --header "app_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/inflections/en/changed"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("app_id", "yyyyyyyy");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("app_key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
var response = await client.GetAsync("/inflections/en/changed");
```

This uses [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) and needs to be inside of an `async` method.

Although `HttpClient` implements `IDisposable`, it is considered best practice to reuse the instance and not dispose of it.

If you are using .NET 4.0 and lower then you can use the older `HttpWebRequest` apis:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/inflections/en/changed");

request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("app_id", "yyyyyyyy");
request.Headers.Add("app_key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know that class didn't exist. Never noticed it was added. Thanks for the HttpClient lesson!

Comment: Glad I could help, if it helped you or the OP feel free to upvote/accept =)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in .Net 4.5 +, you can use `HttpClient` and async methods as well:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("app_id", @"yyyyyyyy");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("app_key", @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/inflections/en/changed");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //Do your thing
    }
}
```